# changing the tabcontrol of tab background color without changing to owner draw fixed

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I would like to change the back color and for color of the tab (the word contains register, login). I wish not to change the property of ownerdrawfixed. How could i do that. Below are the image which i would like to change the back color and fore color of tab. [image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it more readable, say, using proper capitalization?

Comment: Not supported, afaik. I know, owner-drawing looks very hard but it __isn't__.